# Create Wordpress Child plugins

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I knew that we can create child themes for wordpress. But i want to know can we create child plugins. The reason for this is i want to insert some text or something to the existing plugin without touching the plugin files. So my changes will not be affected while upgrading the plugin. Please advice it is possible or not. Thanks

Comment: this one may help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/how-to-create-child-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hooks` & `filters` to modify your plugin function from your theme's `functions.php`. So it won't be affected at plugin upgrade time.

Have a look @ [PluginAPI](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Is there a way to hide the update available notice for some particular plugins? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: :) I am searching for the same. But still if i get anything I will let you know !!

Comment: I found this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-plugin-updates/ But not sure it will work or not !! You can try it !!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It hides all the plugin's notification. But i just want to hide the notification for only two plugins. I will try hooks and filters as you suggested and let you know. Thanks

Comment: to avoid some errors, use simple `function_exists()` check. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

there is no "child" plugin in wordpress... just create a separate plugin to do what you want it to do.  It sounds like you would need to use a filter.